# Adding 2 Strings together - dollar amount

Tags: java, string

I need to add these two together. How is this done?

1. `String total = new String ("$190.00")`
2. `pRequest.getRequestAmount()`

```
public String getRequestAmount() {
    return this.formatMoney(this.fRequest.getRequestAmount());
}
```

Comment: With a plus sign? String addedString = total + pRequest.getRequestAmount(); + here is not addition but string concatenation.

Comment: Convert them to something that can be added with decimal precision (Take your pick. Float, decimal, double, etc...) or what Nicolas suggested (but we don't know what `formatMoney` returns). This is incredibly basic stuff. You could also just Google something like `adding money java`. -1 for no demonstrated research effort whatsoever.

Comment: Do you mean concatenation or addition? Post is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If by add together, you mean joining or concatenating the two strings, then Nicolas has already explained that for you. However, if your intent is to sum them up, then you have to cast the strings to a format such as int i.e int total = Integer.parseInt("string here");